# Migration Rails 6.1, ArgumentError Exception: wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

### Env :

Ruby : 2.6.0

Rails : 6.1.0

### Scenario :

In my project, I have a model `Product` like below :

```
# encoding: utf-8
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  
  validates_presence_of :name
  ...

  default_scope -> { order("name ASC")}
  
end
```

In console I got error

> *** ArgumentError Exception: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)

when I do simply this :

```
(byebug) Product.new
*** ArgumentError Exception: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
```

I saw that the behaves of `default_scope` has been changed in Rails 6.1 by adding `**all_queries**` [PR in Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/41397/files) But I don’t understand. This should have nothing to do with me.

Any one have same problem ?

Comment: do you by any change override an initialize method? or maybe use a gem that overrides it?  if you remove the `default_scope` does it work? what's in your `ApplicationRecord` class?

Comment: can you also specify your active_record gem version, and maybe try this from `rails c` and not from `byebug` and see what happens?

Comment: @Mshka, If I removed default_scope, `Product.new` it works. In `ApplicationRecord` there is only `self.abstract_class = true`. Version Activerecord : 6.1.0. And same problem under rails console.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. There must be some critical gem/override omitted from your description. Does this happen with **ONLY** (!!!!) the lines shown above? Try temporarily deleting everything else from the model.

Comment: @TomLord, Could you have some useful tools to show all locations where default_scope was `override` or `defined origin` ?

Comment: if you post the entire error log we might be able to trace the origin of the error

Comment: @Mshka, I've already posted all. I got only : 2.7.0 :001 > Product.new
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):1
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1))

Comment: Something is hiding the backtrace. Maybe typing `backtrace` into byebug will display more information. As for "showing all locations where `default_scope` was overriden"... I mean, we **could** do down that path, but the stack trace should hopefully reveal this information for us, if it's important! I'm still most suspicious that there's something in the omitted `...` section of your code that's doing some funky override.

Comment: Tome, Mshka, Thank you for your attention. I found why. this Gem https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys